# Detect touch on child node of object in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, touch, sprite-kit

I have a custom class that is an SKNode, which in turn has several SKSpriteNodes in it. Is there a way I can detect touches on these child SKSpriteNodes from my game scene?

I'm working in swift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

   let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

   let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if([yourSprite containsPoint: touchLocation])
    {
         //sprite contains touch
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners

Answer (score 2):

Examine Apple's [SceneKitVehicle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Listings/SceneKitVehicle_AAPLGameView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014549-SceneKitVehicle_AAPLGameView_m-DontLinkElementID_9) demo. Someone kindly [ported it to Swift](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/SceneKitVehicle1.0-Swift/blob/master/SceneKitVehicle/GameView.swift).

The code you want is in the GameView.swift file. In the GameView you'll see the touchesBegan override. Here's my version of it for Swift 2.1:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let scene = self.overlaySKScene else {
        return
    }

    let touch = touches.first!
    let viewTouchLocation = touch.locationInView(self)
    let sceneTouchPoint = scene .convertPointFromView(viewTouchLocation)
    let touchedNode = scene.nodeAtPoint(sceneTouchPoint)

    if (touchedNode.name == "Play") {
        print("play")
    }
}
```

If it's not clear; the GameView is set as the app's view class by way of the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5+

### If you wish to encapsulate touch logic in a node and deal with it locally, you can simply set interaction to true in the corresponding node.

```swift
isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

And then, of course, override touchesBegan to your desire.

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {}
```

If you still wish to receive touches in the scene when touches occur inside a child node, you can, for instance, define a protocol and property for the child node's `delegate` and set the scene to be it.

e.g:

```swift
final class GameScene: SKScene {
    private let childNode = ChildNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        addChild(childNode)
        childNode.delegate = self
    }
}

extension GameScene: TouchDelegate {}

protocol TouchDelegate {
    func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
}

final class ChildNode: SKSpriteNode {
    var delegate: TouchDelegate?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        delegate?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compare the location of your Touch to the location of your SKNode

You can get the location of your touch at one of the following methods, using locationInNode():

- touchesBegan()
- touchesMoved()
- touchesEnded()

Comment: some more detail pls