# How do i detect a touch location in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, location, touch

I'm trying to create gaming and I want to be able to detect where a touch is onscreen. Ive seen several posts about this but all of them have outdated answers.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, share what you have tried.

Comment: @GTG101 Note that questions like this can easy end up closed or downvoted because your question doesn't show an effort in solving the issue. Please see [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect touch on child node of object in SpriteKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328886/detect-touch-on-child-node-of-object-in-spritekit)

Comment: Thanks for the warning.

Comment: Upvoted because you sir just made my day :D

Comment: Thanks, how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project and choose Game (SpriteKit game) if you look inside you will see that there is already shown how you handle touches:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

            sprite.xScale = 0.5
            sprite.yScale = 0.5
            sprite.position = location

            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

            sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

            self.addChild(sprite)
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there is a variable `location` which represent the touch location in the scene's coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot