# How to code IBActions such as TouchDown and TouchUpInside in a sprite kit game project

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, ibaction

I'm trying to develope a new game for iOS using a sprite kit game template in Swift. In my previous app which was a single view application (written in Objective-C) I was able to code `IBActions` corresponding methods for those `IBActions`. Here is the code I used in my Objective-C single view application that worked fine.

A touch down IBAction

```
- (IBAction)LeftArrowTapped:(id)sender {
    [self heroMovementTimerMethodLeft];
}

- (IBAction)RightArrowTapped:(id)sender {
    [self heroMovementTimerMethodRight];
}
```

A touch up inside `IBAction` that cancelled the previous method on touch release

```
- (IBAction)TouchEndedLeft:(id)sender {
    [heroMovementTimerLeft invalidate];
}
- (IBAction)TouchEndedRight:(id)sender {
    [heroMovementTimerRight invalidate];
}
```

and here are the declared methods called upon the touches

```
- (void)heroMovementTimerMethodLeft {
   heroMovementTimerLeft =  
   [NSTimerscheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfhero target:self 
     selector:@selector(heroMovementLeft)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)heroMovementTimerMethodRight {
    heroMovementTimerRight = [NSTimer 
     scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfhero target:self 
     selector:@selector(heroMovementRight)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)heroMovementLeft {
    hero.center = CGPointMake(hero.center.x -.5, hero.center.y);
}

- (void)heroMovementRight {
    hero.center = CGPointMake(hero.center.x +.5, hero.center.y);
}
```

Here is my hero in the sprite kit game project `self.addChild(myLabel)`

```
hero.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height /   
    12)
hero.xScale = 0.5
hero.yScale = 0.5
```

and here is how I am trying to call the action in the sprite kit game

```
func heroMovementLeft () {
heroMovementLeft = CGPointMake(hero.position.x -5 , hero.position.y)
}
```

however it is not working and i get an error message

I think I will have to call the method with a touches began touches ended (if I am wrong please say so) function but how do I format the time interval or `NStimer` used to code the physics for my hero's movement.

Comment: Is your question about how to declare IBAction functions in Swift?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen in swift as well as in a sprite kit game scene in xcode. in a single view application you can just add the IBactions to your storyboard and match the IBactions with the buttons, however in a sprite kit game its a little different. also how do you string movement of a sprite to the touch of the ibaction created. Above in objective-c are the results i want but in my sprite kit game written in swift

Comment: UIKit and SpriteKit are 2 _different_ frameworks that Apple provides.  IBActions will not work.  You are probably looking for `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` and after pulling the location, `containsPoint` to test if the touch location was in whatever "button" you have. EDIT: possibly something described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26330838/5191756).